# postfix sasl send from different from address

Tags: postfix-mta, sasl

I have a working postfix server with sasl auth, and it works perfectly as long as I use the e-mail address in the from-field which belongs to the user I use for sasl_auth.
However, if I would like to send from a different email than the one used in sasl_username, then I get the following error in the log:

```
Client host rejected: Server configuration error (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

What I would like is to have Postfix allow mails from any address in the rcpt to field, but still have the auth mechanism enabled.
How can I do that?
Output of my postconf -n:

```
[root@mailout /]# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mailout.domain.com, mailout.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, , localhost
myhostname = mailout.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.1.1.5
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_inet_interfaces permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtputf8_autodetect_classes = sendmail, verify
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow sasl auth in your smtpd_sender_restrictions or smtpd_relay_restrictions.

`smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated`

There may be more than that particular restriction desired, but that one should fix your issue.